# Filtering one list according a second one

Tags: grep, filtering

I have a genotype file with >950,000 lines like the following ones:

```
24  rs2641123   0   59027434
24  rs4893711   0   59027575
24  rs4047329   0   59027910
24  rs28698289  0   59028502
24  rs2334088   0   59029364
24  rs6568298   0   59029728
24  rs4047343   0   59030922
```

whereby the second column contains a unique code for each line.

I would like to filter the genotype file according to a list that includes only the names of the unique codes to exclude. The list looks like this:

```
rs2641123
rs4893711
rs28698289
rs2334088
```

In principle, the codes in both files are sorted the same way.

I thought of using `grep` but I am not sure how to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to compare the columns in two files using awk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846503/how-to-compare-the-columns-in-two-files-using-awk)

Comment: Oh, this is no duplicate. I just wrote the entire question from scratch. And my focus was on using grep and not awk. Thanks